# Validation one object with another using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, oop

I will explaing the situation.

We have two objects;

The first one contains validation rules, for example:

```
rules = [
   name: {
    length: {
       min: 5
    },
    uppercase: true
   }
]
```

And also we have another object with people:

```
people = {
 name: 'Aleg',
 name: 'Anton',
 name: 'john johnov bla bla'
}
```

My question is - what is the best way to validate the `'people'` obect, using `'rules'` object with JavaScript?

Comment: "Best" is a matter of opinion and thus off-topic for StackOverflow. Regarding your `people` object, should that be an array of objects? You can't have duplicate property names in a single object like that. (Assuming you fix that, wouldn't you just use a loop over the object to be validated, looking up the relevant rules in the `rules` object?)

Comment: what does `uppercase: true` validate? and `people` is an array?

Comment: https://github.com/flatiron/revalidator ...you can use this?

Comment: @nnnnnn I understand this approach, but I wanna find out another one

Comment: @kukkuz this is an example. There are can be different rules.

Comment: @coderredoc I can't use it, because I have boject with specific validation names, which are not the same as there.

Comment: this looks very similar to http://json-schema.org. Any reason not to use that tool?  Also your `people` object is "technically" correct but probably not what you want, as you're writing the same property 3 times ( last one wins usually ). Did you mean to put an array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

declare your `people` in array and `rules` as object. You can use following:

```
var people = [
    {name: 'Aleg'},
    {name: 'Anton'},
    {name: 'john johnov bla bla'}
];

var rules = {
    name: [
        lengthValidator,
        upperCaseValidator
    ]
};

function lengthValidator(string) {
  var isValid = true;
  // here put your validator logic and update isValid
  return {length: isValid};
}

function upperCaseValidator(string) {
  var isValid = true;
  // here put your validator logic and update isValid
  return {uppercase: isValid};
}

function validator(arrObj) {
    _.each(arrObj, (obj) => {
        obj.validations = [];
        _.each(obj, (value, key) => {
            if(rules[key]) {
                _.each(rules[key], (validatorFunction) => {
                    obj.validations.push(validatorFunction(value));
                })
            }
        });
    });
    return arrObj;
}

var validationResult = validator(people);
console.log(validationResult);
```

Here you can check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anshumansworld/28pkyydm/)

Note: I have used [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) for iteration, you can find CDN [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js)

Comment: let me know if you want any clarification